# Split String[] to make different JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to know how i can split this using jquery...

```
 "{"answer":["q1001-a2","q1002-a2","q1003-a2","q1004-a2","q1005-a2","q1006-a2"]}"
```

So i can then make the following JSON...

```
 {
  "d": [
       {
          "question": 1001,
          "answer": "a2"
       },
       {
          "question": 1002,
          "answer": "a2"
       }
       ]
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You suggest to use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function in the title. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the `answer`, split the element by `-`, create the new element and then push it to `d`.

```
var ret = {d: []};
// if you have json string, then you could jQuery.parseJSON to parse it
var obj = {"answer":["q1001-a2","q1002-a2","q1003-a2","q1004-a2","q1005-a2","q1006-a2"]};
var answers = obj.answer, tmp, i;
for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
  tmp = answers[i].split('-');
  ret.d.push({"question": tmp[0], "answer": tmp[1]});
}
```

***[The live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JC8cb/)***.

Comment: sorry had to make a slight change to the JSON how would i use you solution to split - `"{"answer":["q1001-Blend","q1002-Lowlands","q1003-Two","q1004-Ireland","q1005-Bushmills","q1006-Suntory"]}"`

Comment: @thatuxguy Does that make any difference?

Comment: I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @thatuxguy Make sure your `obj.answer` is an array.

Comment: I am passing in this  `"{"d":["q1001-Blend","q1002-Highlands","q1003-Two","q1004-Ireland","q1005-Bushmills","q1006-Hanyu"]}"` into the var obj, is this correct?

Comment: @thatuxguy See my added demo.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

guess this should help.

```
"{"answer":["q1001-a2","q1002-a2","q1003-a2","q1004-a2","q1005-a2","q1006-a2"]}"
```

should look like

```
'{"answer":["q1001-a2","q1002-a2","q1003-a2","q1004-a2","q1005-a2","q1006-a2"]}'
```

You can try to replace 'q1001' and '-' with regex with strings which will match JSON standart, but it's not a universal solution

Answer (score 0):

use a formatting function in jquery like below:

```
var string = "{\"key\":\"val}{ue\"}{'key':'val}{ue'}{ \"asdf\" : 500 }";
var result = string.match(/('.*?')|(".*?")|(\d+)|({)|(:)|(})/g);
var newstring = "";
for (var i in result) {
   var next = parseInt(i) + 1;
   if (next <= result.length) {
      if (result[i] == "}" && result[next] == "{") {
         newstring += "},";
       }
      else {
        newstring += result[i];
   }
 }
```

this code is explained in detail in [jQuery - $.each loop through json code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337766/jquery-each-loop-through-json-code) page